# (C++) How to imagine working of nested loops?

Tags: c++, nested-loops

I have no idea what's going on how to imagine that, one more thing like in 3rd for loop there's a condition that `k<j` but its upper loop `j` is set to 0 and `i` is also 0 then as I think `k=0` if this is right than 0<0 how's that can be valid????

```
void printing_subarrays(int *arr,int n){
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        for(int k=i; k<j; k++){
            cout<<arr[k]<<", ";
        }cout<<endl;
    }cout<<endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Better than "imagining", you could try walking through the code by hand. Get out a piece of paper, make columns for `i`, `j`, and `k` to track their values (as they change), pick values for `arr` and `n`, then follow the instructions of this code as if you were the computer.

Comment: `0 < 0` is a valid statement, which returns `false`.

Comment: You're doing a lot of irrelevant iterations, by the way. If, for instance, `i` is 3 already then for all `j` smaller than or equal to (0, 1, 2, 3) you will discover that `k < j` cannot apply at all, so the loop is not entered either at all. You'd avoid by startking with `j = i + 1`. On the other hand: if you output both `i` and `j` before the inner-most loop and add outputting a line break afterwards you'd see not getting any output if starting with `j = 0` – and you'd see the sub-arrays explicitly instead of all being merged into a single line of output.

Comment: Can you imagine a spreadsheet (Excel or Google Sheets etc)? You outer loop is like writing 0..n-1 as the column headings, then the middle loop is like writing 0..n-1 as the row headings, and the cells are the sequence from `arr[i]` to `arr[j-1]` (which can be empty)

Comment: Alternatively, have you been taught about cross products in maths? Nested loops like this *are* a cross product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it makes much sense for us to explain what's happening, you need to see it for yourself.
Therefore I've added some output lines, which will show you how the values of the variables `i`, `j` and `k` evolve through the loops:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout<<"i=["<<i<<"]"<<endl;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        cout<<"i=["<<i<<"], j=["<<j<<"]"<<endl;
        for(int k=i; k<j; k++){
            cout<<"i=["<<i<<"], j=["<<j<<"], k=["<<k<<"]"<<endl;
            cout<<arr[k]<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: i understand this and how values are actually changing but how you build that logic that's main issue for me i mean how one can understand this logic , that we should abe to think same [one doubt cleared about how values inserted]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try maybe running it? Then it should be apparent...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void printing_subarrays(int *arr, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
        std::cout << arr[k] << ", ";
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  int n = 10;
  std::vector<int> vec(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    vec[i] = i;
  }
  printing_subarrays(vec.data(), n);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i am able to run the program but issue is logic building of nested loops

Comment: You might want to look for a philosophy channel. Stackoverflow is here to help you fix problems in your code.

Comment: any channel you recommend to understand these nested loops better way

Comment: No. You have given no context.